# texStudio more comprehensive autocompletion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have been typing a pretty long hand-written note using TexStudio, and noticed that whenever I typed a previously used long expression with sub/superscripts, it would automatically complete the entire expression, like this:

[image]

However, such behavior does not apply to expressions without sub/superscripts, for example I have $\frac{\prod_k p(x_k\vert \text{Pa}(x_k))}{\int dx_i \prod_k p(x_k\vert \text{Pa}(x_k))}$ typed in the file before, but when I type "\frac{", it would not show up in the dropdown menu for fast autocompletion, so I have to go back to copy/paste it.  Does anyone know if it is possible to make TexStudio auto-completion function more comprehensive to capture such patterns?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks!